# Serve content from a local web server, via Phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, webserver

I am building an HTML / javascript application, and looking at ways in which I can serve the files appropriately.

At the moment, the application runs off a development box webserver, however in the wild, the application needs to be able to run entirely offline, on the iPad.

Without Jailbreaking the iPad, what is the best method for going about this? I've come across this:

http://serversman.com/en/device/sm_ipad.html

Are there alternatives? Would PhoneGap fill this particular hole? At the moment the application is purely javascript / html without the need for server side scripting.

Comment: It seems that you don't really need to "serve" any files, do you? If you are building a pure javascript/html application you could just make a bunch of webpages. The user would than open the index page with his webbrowser.

Comment: Ok, so what would the webbrowser point to? a local file?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution using HTML5 Offline Cache:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH7-SW1

I can upload to a remote server, setup my manifest file, cache once, then go out on the road and still access the application.